# Why this formula code is to be not working on future days (in date difference)?

Tags: excel, date, formula, formulas

I have the formula to be calculated the date difference(interms of hour) in between two Date/time fields but I have only calculated the number of hour in a day is to be in the 9 AM - 9 PM i.e 12 hours per day only the formula calculated and the  calculated days are weekdays not weekendsin a week.

By here I seperated the past and future days compare to the NOW() value the future days are to be shhowing the result with negative sign answer.So as a statement in above it's should be provide the output correctly(only past).

And the if I seleceted to the Calculating date is a week end days like saturday and sunday it's given to the  previous week time (if the date difference is week) + NOW() 's value of time to the calculated  from the 9 AM and if the week end is to be  small to compare to the date difference (just like NOW() is a monday and Calculated date is a yesterday of sunday, saturday like days difference is 2, 3) in a week it's only showing the value of the NOW() value to be calculated to the time from 9 AM
here My code is followingly,

```
IF((MOD(DATEVALUE( Calculating_Date__c )-DATE(1996,01,01), 7) < 5),
((ROUND(12*(
(5*FLOOR((TODAY()-DATE(1996,01,01))/7) +
MIN(5, 
    MOD(TODAY()-DATE(1996,01,01), 7) +
    MIN(1, 24/12*(MOD(NOW()-DATETIMEVALUE('1996-01-01 12:00:00'), 1)))
))
-
(5*FLOOR((DATEVALUE( Calculating_Date__c )-DATE(1996,01,01))/7) +
MIN(5, 
    MOD(DATEVALUE( Calculating_Date__c )-DATE(1996,01,01), 7) +
    MIN(1, 24/12*(MOD( Calculating_Date__c -DATETIMEVALUE('1996-01-01 12:00:00'), 1)))
))
), 0))-
(IF((NOW() > Calculating_Date__c),
(+
IF( ((21 > (VALUE(MID(RIGHT((TEXT(  NOW() + 0.2291)),9),0,2)))) || (9 < (VALUE(MID(RIGHT((TEXT(  NOW() + 0.2291)),9),0,2))))) , 
 (VALUE(MID(RIGHT((TEXT(  NOW() + 0.2291)),9),0,2)) - 9), Null)),
 (-
IF( ((21 > (VALUE(MID(RIGHT((TEXT(  NOW() + 0.2291)),9),0,2)))) || (9 < (VALUE(MID(RIGHT((TEXT(  NOW() + 0.2291)),9),0,2))))) , 
 (VALUE(MID(RIGHT((TEXT(  NOW() + 0.2291)),9),0,2)) - 9), Null))))),

 (IF((NOW() >  Calculating_Date__c ),
(((
 (NOW() -  Calculating_Date__c ) * 5 -
 (MOD(DATEVALUE(Calculating_Date__c) - DATE(1970,1,4),7) - MOD(TODAY() - DATE(1970,1,4),7)) * 2
) / 7 -
IF(MOD(TODAY() - DATE(1970,1,4),7) = 6,1,0) -
IF(MOD( DATEVALUE(Calculating_Date__c) - DATE(1970,1,4),7) = 0,1,0))*12
+
(VALUE(MID(RIGHT((TEXT(  NOW() + 0.2291)),9),0,2)) - 9)),
((
 (NOW() -  Calculating_Date__c ) * 5 -
 (MOD(DATEVALUE(Calculating_Date__c) - DATE(1970,1,4),7) - MOD(TODAY() - DATE(1970,1,4),7)) * 2
) / 7 -
IF(MOD(TODAY() - DATE(1970,1,4),7) = 6,1,0) -
IF(MOD( DATEVALUE(Calculating_Date__c) - DATE(1970,1,4),7) = 0,1,0)*12
-
(VALUE(MID(RIGHT((TEXT(  NOW() + 0.2291)),9),0,2)) - 9)))))
```

So here the I get the output only for the past days not for future days. i.e If selected the date is to be past from the value of NOW() it's provide the output correctly like if select the value of Calculation date is 10/9/2016 then it's provide the value correctly like 77 hours in output.

then the If I select the future day like 10/23/2016 then it's provide the output as -20 hours but the correct output is -60 hours so the formula is provide the output in wrong manner in the only for future days only so that's the problem I want the help to rectify that problem and provide the correct output in the past as well as future days also. so please help me to solve this issue and for answers thanks in advance.

Comment: it is not clear what you want to achieve with your formula. Can you improve the problem description?

Comment: @L.Dutch Now I think I will written clearly What I want and thanks for the suggest to edit once again.

Comment: If you could add the code behind the Calculating_Date_c this may help in finding where the failure is. Also, I see that in some point of the formula you have (+ or (- . Normally Excel would expect some argument before that.

Comment: @L.Dutch , sorry I  am very struggle to got your point sir, Can you give some example to me for make better understand please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to all here the answer of my question is followingly,

```
IF((MOD(DATEVALUE(Calculating_Date__c)-DATE(1996,01,01), 7) < 5),

 (IF((NOW() > Calculating_Date__c),
 ((ROUND(12*(
(5*FLOOR((TODAY()-DATE(1996,01,01))/7) +
MIN(5, 
    MOD(TODAY()-DATE(1996,01,01), 7) +
    MIN(1, 24/12*(MOD(NOW()-DATETIMEVALUE('1996-01-01 12:00:00'), 1)))
))
-
(5*FLOOR((DATEVALUE(Calculating_Date__c)-DATE(1996,01,01))/7) +
MIN(5, 
    MOD(DATEVALUE(Calculating_Date__c )-DATE(1996,01,01), 7) +
    MIN(1, 24/12*(MOD(Calculating_Date__c -DATETIMEVALUE('1996-01-01 12:00:00'), 1)))
))
), 0))
+
IF( (21 > (VALUE(MID(RIGHT((TEXT(NOW() + 0.2291)),9),0,2)))) || (9 < (VALUE(MID(RIGHT((TEXT(  NOW() + 0.2291)),9),0,2)))) , 
 (VALUE(MID(RIGHT((TEXT(NOW() + 0.2291)),9),0,2)) - 9),0 )),
((ROUND(12*(
(5*FLOOR((TODAY()-DATE(1996,01,01))/7) +
MIN(5, 
    MOD(TODAY()-DATE(1996,01,01), 7) +
    MIN(1, 24/12*(MOD(NOW()-DATETIMEVALUE('1996-01-01 12:00:00'), 1)))
))
-
(5*FLOOR((DATEVALUE(Calculating_Date__c )-DATE(1996,01,01))/7) +
MIN(5, 
    MOD(DATEVALUE(Calculating_Date__c )-DATE(1996,01,01), 7) +
    MIN(1, 24/12*(MOD(Calculating_Date__c -DATETIMEVALUE('1996-01-01 12:00:00'), 1)))
))
), 0))
-
IF( (21 > (VALUE(MID(RIGHT((TEXT(NOW() + 0.2291)),9),0,2)))) || (9 < (VALUE(MID(RIGHT((TEXT(NOW() + 0.2291)),9),0,2)))) , 
 (VALUE(MID(RIGHT((TEXT(NOW() + 0.2291)),9),0,2)) - 9), 0)))),

IF((NOW() >  Calculating_Date__c ),
(((
 (NOW() -  Calculating_Date__c ) * 5 -
 (MOD(DATEVALUE(Calculating_Date__c) - DATE(1970,1,4),7) - MOD(TODAY() - DATE(1970,1,4),7)) * 2
) / 7 -
IF(MOD(TODAY() - DATE(1970,1,4),7) = 6,1,0) -
IF(MOD( DATEVALUE(Calculating_Date__c) - DATE(1970,1,4),7) = 0,1,0))*12
+
(VALUE(MID(RIGHT((TEXT(NOW() + 0.2291)),9),0,2)) - 9)),
((
 (NOW() -  Calculating_Date__c ) * 5 -
 (MOD(DATEVALUE(Calculating_Date__c) - DATE(1970,1,4),7) - MOD(TODAY() - DATE(1970,1,4),7)) * 2
) / 7 -
IF(MOD(TODAY() - DATE(1970,1,4),7) = 6,1,0) -
IF(MOD( DATEVALUE(Calculating_Date__c) - DATE(1970,1,4),7) = 0,1,0))*12
-
(VALUE(MID(RIGHT((TEXT(  NOW() + 0.2291)),9),0,2)) - 9)))
```

here I just unified the values are coming inside the value of date difference under the condition based on the past and future days of initally manner.

And also provide the value of the if the value of the saturday and sunday saving the previous value also to be given on the else part of the if class as started in the formula in above there.

(Note: if the formula is only for to be calculated to the value of the date difference in hours on the approximate manner not in based on the time considered like accurate one.). Thank you Mohan (and special thanks to the Mr. Dutch.L for the giving some idea's to the finding bugs).